# alter table InnoDb to MYIASM - .MYD and .MYI not found

Tags: mysql, innodb

I Changed the engine of one of my table from InnoDB to MyIASM using alter command, and phpmyadmin shows that the current engine is MyIASM.
But inside /var/lib/mysql inside the corresponding DB directory , only the .frm file is found for that table .MYD and .MYI are missing. I doubt that the engine has not got changed. Please suggest what has to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify whether the table has indeed been changed issue:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE your_schema.your_table \G
```

Look for the `ENGINE=...` part. There are other ways to do it but this one's just fine. The result of this query is reliable and presents the truth.

Next, let's verify the location. Since you can find the `.FRM` file you are most probably in the right place, but do let's:

```
SELECT @@datadir;
```

And look in there.

Finally, a MyISAM table may [specify](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) a distinct location for data & index, called `DATA DIRECTORY` and `INDEX DIRECTORY`, and seen in the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. I can see no reason why these would be set, but... worth looking at it.

Just guessing as for what happened: is this a large table? Maybe it just took time to `ALTER`, and you were looking even as the table was being rebuilt?

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I could see .MYD and .MYI files. The server had taken time to build the files. Is there any way to see the progress while the server is building the .MYD and .MYI files?

Comment: There's a [nice trick](http://gabrielcain.com/blog/2009/08/05/mysql-alter-table-and-how-to-observe-progress/) for innodb, or you can monitor the progress of file growth on file system for MyISAM, if you know what to expect.